# Blank pudding keycaps

Tags: keyboards

I found pudding keycaps, [e.g.](https://flashquark.com/product/pbt-pudding-keycaps-black-and-white-oem-profile-104-keys/)

[image: Pudding]

And I found blank keycaps, [e.g.](http://www.maxkeyboard.com/max-ansi-104-key-cherry-mx-full-replacement-keycap-set-blank.html)

[image: Blank]

Does anybody know whether there also exist blank pudding keycaps?
I created a sample (please forgive my editing skills):

[image: Blank pudding]

For further reference, I live in Germany and have Cherry MX switches in my Lioncast LK 30 keyboard.